# Identify an old (Russian?) Cartoon. "the 3 ____"

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

I had a cartoon I watched as a child on VHS I'm trying to remember the name of. Here is a list of details I can recall about it.

- Its **old** - pre 1960's (at a guess)
- Its **called "The 3" Something** I *think* the third word in the title began with a **C**
- It was **silent** save music and some sound effects
- It was in **colour**
- There were **3 main characters**, 1 big burly guy, 1 very short guy and 1 tall thin guy each riding inappropriately sized horses.
- I think its **Russian** if not its definitely **Eastern European**

Here is what I can remember of the story line:

The 3 men are riding around the country side and find a village of beautiful women where each find a perfect match for themselves. During the night something happens (Cant remember exactly what one of them, or someone else gets kidnapped and they have to go find them) They go out at night searching and witness witches and other creatures (including a pumpkin on a stick wearing a raggedy shirt) travelling along a road into the woods. They decide to follow them and come across a very Strange tavern, the tavern has a waterwheel which when they first come across it digs into the ground in order to turn the tavern around 360 degrees after which the door opens and smoke comes out of the chimney.

Inside they find various nightmarish creatures drinking and smoking and partying. After a while the barman makes a concoction of various powders and liquids which he places in front of a pair of boots. The drink is then lifted by an invisible force and consumed above the pair of boots revealing a huge red head with legs and arms (I believe its supposed to be the devil).

Various things happen after that, the 3 guys end up beating up the creatures and returning happily to the village of women.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cossacs. Looks like story about Cossacs.
[Russian wiki link](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%28%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%29)

It's Soviet cartoon and there are a number of episodes, actually.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks so much I knew it would be obvious once i heard the last word XD. For anyone interested http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWm-h0iTaSQ thats the full episode i was talking about.